# Mysql DateTime group by 15 mins

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime, group-by

I have a table that looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE `time_table` (
 `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `creationDate` DATETIME NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

I basically store the creation time of certain records in the table. I know if I want to get a count of the records that were created in 15 mins interval I will use something like this

```
SELECT FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(creationDate)/900) AS t, 
COUNT(*) FROM time_table
GROUP BY t
```

That gives me something like this

```
t          COUNT(*)
1434187    1
1434188    3
1434189    2
1434190    2
```

How do I make sense of the first column? If I want it to show me something like

```
t                 COUNT(*)
2:00pm - 2:15pm   1
2:15pm - 2:30pm   3
2:30pm - 2:45pm   2
2:45pm - 3:00pm   2
```

I understand that with some manipulation I could get 1434187 to show up at 2:15pm. Even that might be a good start....then with some logic I could show the entire period. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to just use `>` and `<` in order to get everything within a range, but you may find this to be simpler:

```
SELECT ... 

GROUP BY ( 4 * HOUR( thistime ) + FLOOR( MINUTE( thistime ) / 15 ))
```

from
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,202789,202807

Comment: +1 for the simple and clean solution, but something goes wrong here, the count is not correct... (in the select...) and it works only for 24 hours...

Comment: @Dani - What does your 'where' clause look like?

Answer (score 9):

Here is the solution I use:

```
SELECT  FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(creationDate)/900 ) * 900) AS t, COUNT(*) FROM time_table GROUP BY t
```

Although it arrives 4 years later, hope it will be useful to someone.

Answer (score 5):

Answer 2 only works for 24hours - try this one;

```
SELECT ...

GROUP BY year(date),month(date),day(date),( 4 * HOUR( date ) + FLOOR( MINUTE( date ) / 15 ))
```