# Check if user has uploaded more or exactly 50 files in less than two minutes MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

So I have an image uploader, and I want to create a minimal bot protection.
My table structure looks like this:

```
| ID | uploader_ip | image_name | image_url_id | date
------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 127.0.0.1   | bla.jpg    | fsdJGf       | UNIX Timestamp  (UPDATE ON: Create)
```

I want to check if there are more or exactly 50 images/rows, that were created in less or exactly **two minutes.**

**How can I do that?**

Comment: You should read about [triggers](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/introduction-to-mysql-triggers/). Also, you could do a simple `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ip = ? ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 20, 1` and then check the date of that one against the current date.

Comment: In two minutes on the clock?  Or, two minutes between two uploads?  That's an important distinction that makes this an easy problem, or a very difficult problem.  For the hard problem, see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/6551214/362536

Comment: @Brad Good point, and what I mean is, if there were created exactly 50 or more rows, in two minutes together, so it will check everyone's date, and if these dates are interval 2 minutes, get it.

Comment: @JonyKale In that case, see that link I sent you.  Your question is exactly the same, just with a different time interval.

Comment: @brad Actually it wokrs with two tables, Im not sure how to get it,.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to construct a query that incorporates count and group, and puts a range on the date column.  If you were to do this for only the most recent two minutes, your query would look something like this:

```
select count(*) from your_table where uploader_ip="<some ip>" and date > (now() - interval 2 minute) group by uploader_ip;
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the query

```
Select count(*) from table 
where 
table.date >  now() - interval 2 minute
-- or the function date_sub(now(), interval 2 minute)
and id = 1
```

If you want all user id that have uploads within a 2 minute window:

```
select id, 
  (select count(*) 
    from table 
    where id = t.id 
    and date > t.date - interval 1 minute 
    and date < t.date + interval 1 minute
  ) as total
from table t
where total >= 50
```