# Query Group where Timediff is less than 1 minute

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am trying to figure out how to group a query result where the final Grouping should happen where the time difference is less than let's say one minute.

I have watermeter that logs my water usage and I am trying to group the results so that the graphs will make more sense.  My sql queries for grouping the water usage per Year, Month, Day and hour are perfect, but then I would like to drill down to where the final result shows me a grouping where as an example I water the grass.

My Table Structure looks like:

```
 id liter   total_liters    date         time       dater
9   3       184           2020/12/06    16:14:58    2020/12/06 16:14
10  1       185           2020/12/06    16:15:04    2020/12/06 16:15
11  3       188           2020/12/06    16:26:49    2020/12/06 16:26
12  2       190           2020/12/06    16:26:55    2020/12/06 16:26
13  2       192           2020/12/06    16:27:01    2020/12/06 16:27
14  1       193           2020/12/06    17:32:16    2020/12/06 17:32
15  1       194           2020/12/06    17:32:22    2020/12/06 17:32
16  1       195           2020/12/06    17:32:28    2020/12/06 17:32
17  1       196           2020/12/06    17:32:35    2020/12/06 17:32
18  1       197           2020/12/06    17:32:41    2020/12/06 17:32
19  1       198           2020/12/06    17:32:47    2020/12/06 17:32
20  1       199           2020/12/06    17:32:53    2020/12/06 17:32
21  1       200           2020/12/06    17:32:59    2020/12/06 17:32
22  1       201           2020/12/06    17:35:05    2020/12/06 17:35
23  1       202           2020/12/06    17:35:17    2020/12/06 17:35
24  1       203           2020/12/06    17:35:23    2020/12/06 17:35
25  1       204           2020/12/06    17:35:29    2020/12/06 17:35
26  1       205           2020/12/06    17:35:41    2020/12/06 17:35
27  1       206           2020/12/06    17:43:05    2020/12/06 17:43
28  3       209           2020/12/06    17:43:11    2020/12/06 17:43
29  2       211           2020/12/06    17:43:17    2020/12/06 17:43
30  2       213           2020/12/06    17:43:23    2020/12/06 17:43
31  2       215           2020/12/06    17:43:29    2020/12/06 17:43
32  3       218           2020/12/06    17:43:36    2020/12/06 17:43
33  2       220           2020/12/06    17:43:42    2020/12/06 17:43
```

And my current query looks like:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dater,'%H:%i') AS dater,
                    YEAR(dater),
                    MONTHNAME(dater),
                    DAY(dater),
                    HOUR(dater),
                    MINUTE(dater),
                    SUM(liter) as liter
                    FROM watermeter
                    WHERE date LIKE '2020-12-08'
                    GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTHNAME(date), DAY(dater), HOUR(dater), MINUTE(dater)
                    ORDER BY id ASC`
```

The result should be to sum the Liters together by grouping them by Year then Month then Day then Hour and then it should group the results where the time difference is less than 60 seconds.

I might end up by grouping them Year, Month, Day and then by time difference is less than 60 seconds .

Like

```
2020-12-06   17:35:05     5 Liters
2020-12-06   17:43:05     13 Liters
```

Here is a phpmyaddmin sql dump if it helps

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.6.6deb5
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost:3306
-- Generation Time: Dec 10, 2020 at 07:27 AM
-- Server version: 10.3.17-MariaDB-0+deb10u1
-- PHP Version: 7.3.11-1~deb10u1

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `mysensors`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `watermeter`
--

CREATE TABLE `watermeter` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `liter` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total_liters` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  `dater` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `watermeter`
--

INSERT INTO `watermeter` (`id`, `liter`, `total_liters`, `date`, `time`, `dater`) VALUES
(9, 3, 184, '2020-12-06', '16:14:58', '2020-12-06 16:14:58'),
(10, 1, 185, '2020-12-06', '16:15:04', '2020-12-06 16:15:04'),
(11, 3, 188, '2020-12-06', '16:26:49', '2020-12-06 16:26:49'),
(12, 2, 190, '2020-12-06', '16:26:55', '2020-12-06 16:26:55'),
(13, 2, 192, '2020-12-06', '16:27:01', '2020-12-06 16:27:01'),
(14, 1, 193, '2020-12-06', '17:32:16', '2020-12-06 17:32:16'),
(15, 1, 194, '2020-12-06', '17:32:22', '2020-12-06 17:32:22'),
(16, 1, 195, '2020-12-06', '17:32:28', '2020-12-06 17:32:28'),
(17, 1, 196, '2020-12-06', '17:32:35', '2020-12-06 17:32:35'),
(18, 1, 197, '2020-12-06', '17:32:41', '2020-12-06 17:32:41'),
(19, 1, 198, '2020-12-06', '17:32:47', '2020-12-06 17:32:47'),
(20, 1, 199, '2020-12-06', '17:32:53', '2020-12-06 17:32:53'),
(21, 1, 200, '2020-12-06', '17:32:59', '2020-12-06 17:32:59'),
(22, 1, 201, '2020-12-06', '17:35:05', '2020-12-06 17:35:05'),
(23, 1, 202, '2020-12-06', '17:35:17', '2020-12-06 17:35:17'),
(24, 1, 203, '2020-12-06', '17:35:23', '2020-12-06 17:35:23'),
(25, 1, 204, '2020-12-06', '17:35:29', '2020-12-06 17:35:29'),
(26, 1, 205, '2020-12-06', '17:35:41', '2020-12-06 17:35:41'),
(27, 1, 206, '2020-12-06', '17:43:05', '2020-12-06 17:43:05'),
(28, 3, 209, '2020-12-06', '17:43:11', '2020-12-06 17:43:11'),
(29, 2, 211, '2020-12-06', '17:43:17', '2020-12-06 17:43:17'),
(30, 2, 213, '2020-12-06', '17:43:23', '2020-12-06 17:43:23'),
(31, 2, 215, '2020-12-06', '17:43:29', '2020-12-06 17:43:29'),
(32, 3, 218, '2020-12-06', '17:43:36', '2020-12-06 17:43:36'),
(33, 2, 220, '2020-12-06', '17:43:42', '2020-12-06 17:43:42');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `watermeter`
--
ALTER TABLE `watermeter`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `dater` (`dater`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `watermeter`
--
ALTER TABLE `watermeter`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1061;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

UPDATE 1.

Making little progress I think - Totals are not right yet.

```
SELECT '(a.dater, b.dater)', DATE_FORMAT(a.dater,'%H:%i') AS dater,
                        YEAR(a.dater),
                        MONTHNAME(a.dater),
                        DAY(a.dater),
                        HOUR(a.dater),
                        MINUTE(a.dater),
                        a.time,
                        SUM(a.liter) as liter
                        FROM watermeter a
                        INNER JOIN watermeter b
                        ON b.dater >= a.dater
                        WHERE b.dater <= DATE_ADD(a.dater, INTERVAL 60 SECOND)
                        AND a.date LIKE '2020-12-08' GROUP BY YEAR(a.date), MONTHNAME(a.date), DAY(a.dater), HOUR(a.dater), MINUTE(a.dater)
                        ORDER BY a.id ASC
```

Update2

So Update one does not give me the correct result. Tried now the following that I got from : [MySQL GROUP BY DateTime +/- 3 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551214/mysql-group-by-datetime-3-seconds)      but also no joy yet.

```
SELECT COUNT(liter),DAY(dater),HOUR(dater),MINUTE(dater) 
FROM watermeter
JOIN (SELECT watermeter.id, MAX(S.dater) AS ChainStartTime 
FROM watermeter 
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT a.dater 
      FROM watermeter a 
      LEFT JOIN watermeter b 
      ON (b.dater >= a.dater - INTERVAL 60 SECOND 
      AND b.dater < a.dater) 
      WHERE b.dater IS NULL 
      AND a.date LIKE '2020-12-06') S 
      ON watermeter.dater >= S.dater 
      GROUP BY watermeter.id) GroupingQuery
ON watermeter.id = GroupingQuery.id
GROUP BY GroupingQuery.ChainStartTime
```

Comment: Sorry for that, I removed the picture and added the Table structure as code.

Comment: try only with GROUP BY  HOUR(dater), MINUTE(dater)

Comment: That is how I have it now, but the results is not want I want.  I would like to only have the minutes grouped where the time difference is less than 1 minute or 30 seconds.  The end result will then group where water was running and indicate an event instead of just grouping by minute.  Hope it makes sense .

Comment: This is exactly what I would like to archive, but the code does not work on my MariaDB ? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17669/grouping-records-based-on-intervals-of-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the difference in time from the previous row:

```
select 
   id, 
   liter, 
   total_liters, 
   dater,
   lead(dater) over (order by dater) as "lead",  
   timediff(dater, lead(dater) over (order by dater)) as d1
from watermeter
order by dater;
```

output:

```
+----+-------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| id | liter | total_liters | dater               | lead                | d1        |
+----+-------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
|  9 |     3 |          184 | 2020-12-06 16:14:58 | 2020-12-06 16:15:04 | -00:00:06 |
| 10 |     1 |          185 | 2020-12-06 16:15:04 | 2020-12-06 16:26:49 | -00:11:45 |
| 11 |     3 |          188 | 2020-12-06 16:26:49 | 2020-12-06 16:26:55 | -00:00:06 |
| 12 |     2 |          190 | 2020-12-06 16:26:55 | 2020-12-06 16:27:01 | -00:00:06 |
| 13 |     2 |          192 | 2020-12-06 16:27:01 | 2020-12-06 17:32:16 | -01:05:15 |
| 14 |     1 |          193 | 2020-12-06 17:32:16 | 2020-12-06 17:32:22 | -00:00:06 |
| 15 |     1 |          194 | 2020-12-06 17:32:22 | 2020-12-06 17:32:28 | -00:00:06 |
| 16 |     1 |          195 | 2020-12-06 17:32:28 | 2020-12-06 17:32:35 | -00:00:07 |
| 17 |     1 |          196 | 2020-12-06 17:32:35 | 2020-12-06 17:32:41 | -00:00:06 |
```

etc...

Then determine which times you would like to see, because they have a difference to their previous row which is larger than 60 seconds.
(The `id` of the column is show in `x`)

```
with cte as  (
   select id, 
      dater,
      liter,
      total_liters, 
      d1, 
      abs(time_to_sec(d1)) as g1,
      case when abs(time_to_sec(d1))>60 then id else 0 end as x
   from (
      select 
      id, 
      liter, 
      total_liters, 
      dater,
      lead(dater) over (order by dater) as "lead",  
      timediff(dater, lead(dater) over (order by dater)) as d1
   from watermeter
   order by dater
   ) tmp1 
)
select * from cte;
```

output:

```
+----+---------------------+-------+--------------+-----------+------+----+
| id | dater               | liter | total_liters | d1        | g1   | x  |
+----+---------------------+-------+--------------+-----------+------+----+
|  9 | 2020-12-06 16:14:58 |     3 |          184 | -00:00:06 |    6 |  0 |
| 10 | 2020-12-06 16:15:04 |     1 |          185 | -00:11:45 |  705 | 10 |
| 11 | 2020-12-06 16:26:49 |     3 |          188 | -00:00:06 |    6 |  0 |
| 12 | 2020-12-06 16:26:55 |     2 |          190 | -00:00:06 |    6 |  0 |
| 13 | 2020-12-06 16:27:01 |     2 |          192 | -01:05:15 | 3915 | 13 |
| 14 | 2020-12-06 17:32:16 |     1 |          193 | -00:00:06 |    6 |  0 |
| 15 | 2020-12-06 17:32:22 |     1 |          194 | -00:00:06 |    6 |  0 |
| 16 | 2020-12-06 17:32:28 |     1 |          195 | -00:00:07 |    7 |  0 |
```

etc...

Next step is to determine the max(id) which 'belongs' to the `x`:

```
with cte as  (
   select id, 
      dater,
      liter,
      total_liters, 
      d1, 
      abs(time_to_sec(d1)) as g1,
      case when abs(time_to_sec(d1))>60 then id else 0 end as x
   from (
      select 
      id, 
      liter, 
      total_liters, 
      dater,
      lead(dater) over (order by dater) as "lead",  
      timediff(dater, lead(dater) over (order by dater)) as d1
   from watermeter
   order by dater
   ) tmp1 
)
  select 
    id,
    dater,
    liter,
    total_liters 
    ,d1,
    g1,
      x, 
      (select min(x)-1 from cte c2 where c2.id>c1.x and c2.x>0) as y
  from cte c1
  where c1.x<>0
;
```

output:

```
+----+---------------------+-------+--------------+-----------+------+----+------+
| id | dater               | liter | total_liters | d1        | g1   | x  | y    |
+----+---------------------+-------+--------------+-----------+------+----+------+
| 10 | 2020-12-06 16:15:04 |     1 |          185 | -00:11:45 |  705 | 10 |   12 |
| 13 | 2020-12-06 16:27:01 |     2 |          192 | -01:05:15 | 3915 | 13 |   20 |
| 21 | 2020-12-06 17:32:59 |     1 |          200 | -00:02:06 |  126 | 21 |   25 |
| 26 | 2020-12-06 17:35:41 |     1 |          205 | -00:07:24 |  444 | 26 | NULL |
+----+---------------------+-------+--------------+-----------+------+----+------+
```

Note that `x` and `y` are the minimum and maximum `id` for your group.

Finally (this messy stuff):

```
with cte as  (
   select id, 
      dater,
      liter,
      total_liters, 
      d1, 
      abs(time_to_sec(d1)) as g1,
      case when abs(time_to_sec(d1))>60 then id else 0 end as x
   from (
      select 
      id, 
      liter, 
      total_liters, 
      dater,
      lead(dater) over (order by dater) as "lead",  
      timediff(dater, lead(dater) over (order by dater)) as d1
   from watermeter
   order by dater
   ) tmp1 
)
select
   id,
   dater,
   (select sum(liter) from watermeter where id between x and y) as rain
from ( 
  select 
    id,
    dater,
    liter,
    total_liters 
    ,d1,
    g1,
      x, 
      (select min(x)-1 from cte c2 where c2.id>c1.x and c2.x>0) as y
  from cte c1
  where c1.x<>0
) tmp2
;
```

gives output:

```
+------+---------------------+------+
| id   | dater               | rain |
+------+---------------------+------+
|   10 | 2020-12-06 16:15:04 |    6 |
|   13 | 2020-12-06 16:27:01 |    9 |
|   21 | 2020-12-06 17:32:59 |    5 |
|   26 | 2020-12-06 17:35:41 | NULL |
+------+---------------------+------+
```

I do hope this is close to the expected output...

Comment: Thank you very much for the very detailed explanation - whow.  I am trying the queries step by step.  The first one runs just fine. The rest not.  Problem seems to come in on the second step with the line ending with "lead"  - Still trying to figure out what is wrong here ?  Just fyi - I am running mariaDB .

Comment: The `lead` and `lag` functions where introduced in Mariadb 10.2  (docs: [LAG](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/lag/), [LEAD](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/lead/) )

Comment: Hmmm,  should then be fine on my system - Running on Raspberry pi - 10.3.17-MariaDB-0+deb10u1  . Battling to find the issue- query runs but with zero results.

Comment: Copying (and pasting) the entire error message might help.... 

Comment: Will do , just busy updating my raspberry pi  top make sure it is not a version thing  :-)

Comment: Pi has been updated but still same.  What I found now is that from the command line, all queries run just fine (been testing the whole time from phpmyadmin and from my php script.)      From phpmyadmin the query jsut runs and finishes within a second with no output.  If I run it from my php script, I get the following error :  `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'lead' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in /1query.php on line 28`

Comment: Because your question does not have the tag `php` this should be asked in a different question.  But make sure to CHECK the syntax first for typing errors.... 

Comment: Thanks, will do - Just FYI - your answer is almost perfect to what I want to achieve.

Comment: I rejected your edit because it was about data which is not provided in the original question. It would be of much more help to create a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) with enough data for your problem.

Comment: It is fine, thank you.  I will see what I can do with the code else if I cannot get it right I will change my python capturing script to only upload as a total to mysql db as a pre-calculated liters value.  This will limit me a bit in the future but it's fine.  I will mark you answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Luuk's code and learning a lot about "case" and "lag" and lead" and using nested selects etc.  I was able to get a working query for what I wanted.

```
SET @wgroup := 0;
with cte as  (
   select   
      id, 
      dater,
      liter,
      total_liters, 
      d1, 
      abs(time_to_sec(d1)) as g1,
      case when abs(time_to_sec(d1))>60 then @wgroup := @wgroup+1 else @wgroup end as wgroup
   from (
      select 
      id, 
      liter, 
      total_liters, 
      dater,
      (case
        WHEN lag(dater) over (order by dater) IS NULL
    THEN    timediff(dater, lead(dater) over (order by dater))  
    ELSE    timediff(dater, lag(dater) over (order by dater))        
    END) AS d1  
   from watermeter where date like '2020-12-06' 
   order by dater
   ) tmp1  
)
    (select dater,
        wgroup,
    SUM(liter) 
       from cte
       GROUP BY wgroup)  
;
```

With this I was able to sum all values where the time difference is less than 60 second from without loosing a single line.

```
+---------------------+--------+------------+
| dater               | wgroup | SUM(liter) |
+---------------------+--------+------------+
| 2020-12-06 16:14:58 |      0 |          4 |
| 2020-12-06 16:26:49 |      1 |          7 |
| 2020-12-06 17:32:16 |      2 |          8 |
| 2020-12-06 17:35:05 |      3 |          5 |
| 2020-12-06 17:43:05 |      4 |        308 |
| 2020-12-06 19:19:03 |      5 |        120 |
| 2020-12-06 19:31:29 |      6 |          4 |
| 2020-12-06 19:34:48 |      7 |          1 |
| 2020-12-06 20:30:08 |      8 |          1 |
| 2020-12-06 21:27:06 |      9 |         23 |
+---------------------+--------+------------+
```