# grouping by similar entries / not identical entries / values within certain range

Tags: mysql, grouping

Im using mysql
When I want to group by time all entries that have less time difference then x seconds, what function I need to use?

Example group this into two groups by time?

| time | id | ok |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.22 02:30:45 | 123 | 1 |
| 01.01.22 02:30:44 | 456 | 1 |
| 01.01.22 02:30:43 | 789 | 0 |
| 01.01.22 05:14:11 | 222 | 1 |

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.x or MySQL 5.x?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL GROUP BY DateTime +/- 3 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551214/mysql-group-by-datetime-3-seconds)

Comment: its mysql 5.x. yes this does answer my question