# Grouping timestamp every 30 minutes

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to group my timestamp every 30 minutes.

I want my result to be like this:

```
2016-03-09 00:00:00
2016-03-09 00:30:00
2016-03-09 01:00:00
```

Instead, my results are this:

```
2016-03-09 00:00:23
2016-03-09 00:35:02
2016-03-09 01:00:03
```

The query that I'm using is this

```
SELECT timestamp
FROM a.tablename
WHERE name = 'example' AND timestamp LIKE '2016-03-09%'
GROUP BY ROUND(((60/30) * HOUR(timestamp) + FLOOR( MINUTE(timestamp) / 30)));
```

How can I have my desired results? I've researched other answers on SO and non of the answers helped

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the basic query to group by 30 minutes interval.

```
SELECT 
FROM_UNIXTIME(ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)/(30* 60)) * (30*60)) thirtyHourInterval
FROM tablename
GROUP BY ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)/(30* 60));
```

**Note:** `ROUND()` may lead you towards wrong output. Use the following query instead. Look at the following example:

```
SELECT ROUND(3.7), ROUND(4.2);
```

**Result:** `4    4`.

***Both lies in the same segment. The same holds for the above query while rounding the `timestamp` of different segments might fall in the same segment  thus leading towards wrong output***

**[The following query is Recommended]**

```
SELECT 
FROM_UNIXTIME((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`timestamp`) DIV (30* 60) ) * (30*60)) thirtyHourInterval
FROM tablename
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`timestamp`) DIV (30* 60)
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8f355/1/0)

---

Alternatively you can adopt the following query.

```
SELECT 
FROM_UNIXTIME(ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)/(30* 60)) * (30*60)) thirtyHourInterval
FROM tablename
GROUP BY ( 4 * HOUR( `timestamp` ) + FLOOR( MINUTE( `timestamp` ) / 30 ));
```

[Relatedpost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289345/mysql-datetime-group-by-15-mins)

Comment: Yeah this is perfect! Unfortunately, I have a wait a couple minutes to accept this. Thanks!

Comment: Yes I used your recommended query and I can confirm it works too

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use `to_seconds()`, truncate the value, and then re-create the `datetime` value:

```
select date_add(0, interval floor(to_seconds(timestamp) / (30 * 60)) second) as timestamp
from a.tablename
where name = 'example' and timestamp >= '2016-03-09' and timestamp < '2016-03-10'
group by date_add(0, interval floor(to_seconds(timestamp) / (30 * 60)) second)
order by 1;
```

Comment: Although your entire query didn't work in my case, your `WHERE` clause helped me get just that day. so +1